# Replacing last word in string using ArcGIS field calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

In this table I need to change the last word from field !name! using the text from field !abbreviation!

[image]

I was trying to use Python parser to get the text from !name! field without last word and then add !Abbreviation! field. But my expression returns an error:

```
!Abbreviation! = !name!.split(' ')[:-1]
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
'{} {}'.format(' '.join(!name!.split()[:-1]), !Abbreviation!)
```

Explanation:

- Your code to split all of the name except the last word was correct.
- `' '.join...` converts the list back into a string
- `'{} {}'.format...` creates a new string from the the join command & the abbreviation field.

In the Field Calculator you don't put `!Abbreviation! =` in the expression. The destination  is determined automatically by the field used to open it. I believe you want the results to go back into the name field, so open the Field Calculator from there.